# What is this round 6 pin connector?

Tags: connector, identification

I am trying to connect to an e-bike controller to reprogram it, and have to find the female counterpart to this connector for this purpose. Ideally, I want to find the part that will plug into this.
I've spent a couple of hours going through lists of connectors, but no luck so far.

Here is a photo showing the cable connector I have:

- 6 pins
- external diameter ~8mm
- internal diameter ~6mm
- as shown on the photo, there is a flat part on the top side of the photo
- the connection is made by pushing the other part in, no screwing or baionets
- given that it is on an outdoor bicycle kit, I'd think it has a reasonable water-tightness rating.
- it says "JULET" on the side of the connector (it's hard to see this on the photo)
- the casing is somewhat flexible plastic material

[image]

Any tips would be great!

Comment: two tips ... that is a male connector ... do an internet search

Comment: Kind of looks like an XLR (male) connector. I can't seem to find Julet's website to get an exact part number. It also looks like it has a hardware lock on the top where it's straight instead of a complete circle so even if  you were trying to replace the female counterpart, you wouldn't be able to plug it in.

Comment: @KingDuken:  It is definitely not an XLR - they are round, without a flat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its Higo julet waterproof signal motor battery connector.

Its for eBikes, you can see the exact same connector [here](https://www.eco-ebike.com/products/5-pin-to-6-pin-display-conversion-cable-for-tsdz2).

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't look exactly right. I'll amend the question, but I am indeed looking for the female part that will plug into the male part on the photo.

Comment: I changed the answer, now its exactly the same.

Comment: @CFCBazarcom that is definitely the right one, thanks! Does this mean this is not a "standard" part that I can purchase from an electronics retailer?

Comment: Please mark my answer as the solution. I don't know how much its sold, a standard part is a part that has a lot of sales and can easily be found. This part is hard to find, it might be easy to find in your region, but it might be only 1 piece available in 1 store somewhere. If you can, order from the shop in the link or try to search for an eBike shop, eBike repair shops, eBike parts or something similar. Otherwise google is your friend.